# Show or hide on multiple element using class in React

Tags: reactjs

I am using the class component here Consider selecting Yes or No value depending on whether to show or hide the `div`.

I wanted to do the same thing with multiple `div`. But here if I am selecting yes then both the div are open. And not close to clicked on no value.

Here is my code:

```
class PersonalInfo extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.divstatus1 = this.divstatus1.bind(this);
        this.divstatus2 = this.divstatus2.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            value1: 'no',
            value2: 'no'
        };
    }

    divstatus1 = (e) => {
        this.setState({ value1: e.target.value1 });
    }

    divstatus2 = (e) => {
        this.setState({ value2: e.target.value2 });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3 className="showbase_header">Passport Details</h3>


                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="orderby"> Do you have passport ?</label>
                    <select className="form-control orderby" onChange={this.divstatus1}>
                        <option value="" selected>Select</option>
                        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                    </select>
                    <br></br>

                    <div className={this.state.value1} >

                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-6 form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="name">Passport Number
                                    <span className="required">*</span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" id="firstname" aria-required="true" size={30} name="firstname" className="form-control" placeholder="" />

                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-6 form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="name">Place Of Issue
                                    <span className="required">*</span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" id="lastname" aria-required="true" size={30} name="lastname" className="form-control" placeholder="" />

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-sm-6 form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="expirydate">Expiry Date
                                    <span className="required">*</span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="date" id="expirydate" aria-required="true" size={30} name="expirydate" className="form-control" placeholder="" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-sm-6 form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="issuedate">Issue Date
                                    <span className="required">*</span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="date" id="issuedate" aria-required="true" size={30} name="issuedate" className="form-control" placeholder="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <h3 className="showbase_header">Representation</h3>

                    <select className="form-control orderby" onChange={this.divstatus2}>
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                    </select><br />
                    <div className={this.state.value2} >

                        <div class="row">

                            <div className="col-sm-6 form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="name">Name
                                    <span className="required">*</span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" id="name" aria-required="true" size={30} name="name" className="form-control" placeholder="" />

                            </div>

                            <div className="col-sm-6 form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="number">Contact Number
                                    <span className="required">*</span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="number" id="name" aria-required="true" size={30} name="number" className="form-control" placeholder="" />

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PersonalInfo;
```

I have added in `main.css`

```
.yes{display: block;}
.no{display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
divstatus1 = (e) => {
    this.setState({ value1: e.target.value });
}

divstatus2 = (e) => {
    this.setState({ value2: e.target.value });
}
```

`option` does not have an attribute called `value1` or `value2`